# generator not defined error when using await in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a project using Angular 4.4.6 version. [this is version of angular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYoYS.png)

When i config it and running, it's ok. But have problem when using async and await in function onSubmit Login: login.component.ts:

```
public async onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    if (this.form.valid) {
      const user: ILoginUser = {
        UserName: this.form.value.username,
        Password: this.form.value.password
      };
      this.isLoginSuccessful = await this._loginService.login(user, true);
    }
  }
```

I don't know why throw exception [exception here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCuey.png). I thinks that problem in tsconfig.json but i don't know exactly position i'm wrong.

This is tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "tslint-language-service"
      }
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "forkChecker": true,
    "useWebpackText": true
  },
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}

Everyone please help me, many thanks!
```

Answer (score 0):

I will advice to use subscribe instead of using async and await. Please let me know if you face any error in this.

> > await works for promise, while your login function must be returning an observable, so you might want to convert the observable to promise, if you must use await like:
> > >> await  .login(,,).toPromise()

```js
public onSubmit() {
  this.submitted = true;
  if (this.form.valid) {
    const user: ILoginUser = {
      UserName: this.form.value.username,
      Password: this.form.value.password
    };
    this._loginService.login(user, true).subscribe((bool) => {
      this.isLoginSuccessful = bool;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i think i will change to using subscribe instead for async and await. 
Angular new version will support subscribe more.

Comment: async await is not exaclty same as subscribe, they make the code to wait, while subscribe does not make code to wait

Comment: Sure, i must to learn more about subscrible in angular 4.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please let me know if you the answer does not address your query

Comment: Thanks for your help, i have another solution for my project.